# jquery hover only works on click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, hover

i have this little jquery code running on jquery 1.10.1, what i want to do is quite basically
console log on hover events on hovering over li class dash_item, but it only works when i click the item, not on hover

CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dash_item').on({

       mouseenter: function(){
        console.log("im here");
      },

      mouseleave: function(){
        console.log("im out");
      }
    });
});
```

the jsfiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/JQAw3/

Comment: It works on hover for me, using Chrome, what browser are you using?

Comment: im using chrome aswell, however i just tried on mozilla and it works, thats very weird

Comment: It works for me on firefox

Comment: You have gremlins in your computer, only explanation.

Answer (score 43):

Seems to be a Google Chrome bug that can happen when you have a website open for a long time, including the Dev Tools.

I had the same problems, tried everything I could.

In the end, a simple browser restart helped.

Maybe it's also enough if you simply open the website in another tab.

**Edit 2015-06-15:** I encounter this problem every time I'm working on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` in Chrome. For me, it's definitely enough to just close the tab and open the website in another.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be enough to open in another tab.  I had to kill the browser.  Thank you!

Comment: Confirmed restart worked.  Wasted an hour on this, but you probably saved me a day!

Comment: I'm sad to report this is still a problem as of the time of this post. Thanks, you saved me tons of time!

Comment: +1000. One year later, and I just stumbled upon this same bug (using Chromium on Ubuntu)! I lost a few hours trying to solve this as it stopped working just after some code changes and I thought the problem came from my code!!!! I closed the tab and opened the page again in a new tab and my code worked again. I almost never restart Chromium so I owe you a lot of debugging time!

Comment: I noticed this only happens for me when Chrome Responsive view is active.  `Command + Shift + M` will deactivate and the hover works again.

Comment: Having same bug on Chrome. Closing and opening browser fixes it as mentioned above

Comment: I had this issue on Safari. Anyway this is not going to affect the end user. They won't use the Dev tools.

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't - same problems with hover as mouseenter

I have had developer tools open for some time

Opened the page in firefox and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can try the jQuery hover() function.  It takes a handlerIn and handlerOut.

Comment: The .hover() method binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave events. You can use it to simply apply behavior to an element during the time the mouse is within the element. In other words, there's no difference.

Comment: I know but it is an easier function to add imo.

Comment: @CWitty then it should be a comment, not an answer :)

Comment: Sorry new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

works fine with hover

http://jsfiddle.net/blackjim/JQAw3/4/

```
$('.dash_item').hover(
    function () {
        console.log("im here");
    },
    function () {
        console.log("im out");
    }
);
```

Comment: As with CWitty's answer, hover is just shorthand for mouseenter and mouseleave.

Comment: Yeah I agree, but it's less code. Since he wants to handle both cases here.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving this here in case anyone else stumbles across this. In early 2015 this is still a 'feature' in chrome/chromium where if the page is being viewed as a file (NOT served from a webserver) the mouse position events like `mouseenter`, `mouseleave`, `mouseover`, etc do not fire. Don't know if that was OP's issue but was mine when I stumbled across this.